# Lumen: JWT Authentication with none users table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, lumen

**In Short, I receives the following error :**

```
{
  "message": "Undefined index: password",
  "status_code": 500
}
```

**A liitle background :**

I have a `users` table, And a `pincodes` table, The `users` table have two columns `mobile_number`, and `status`, I am sending sms to mobile number in users table, Sms have a secret code then i saves that code along with the `user_id` in `pincodes` table.

So the authentication will apply on `pincodes`, Where i have `user_id` and the `code` to verify that the user is authentic or not. I am using lumen micro framework, With JWT Authentication [library](https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt) . So i changed my `Pincode` model to same like `User` Model.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;

class Pincode extends Model implements
AuthenticatableContract,
AuthorizableContract {
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    protected $table = 'pincodes';
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

The verify method request type is post(Shown below), And the params are `user_id`, and `code`. Which i provides correct.

And the verification method where the token is supposed to generate :

```
public function verify(Request $request) {
  $uid = $request->get('uid');
  $pinCode = $request->get('code');

  $findPinCode = \App\Pincode::where('uid', $uid)->where('code', $pinCode)->first();
  if (!$findPinCode) {
      return response()->json([
          'message' => 'No pin Code found',
          'code' => 404,
      ]);
  }

  $findPinCode->status = 'v';
  $findPinCode->dateVerify = Carbon::now();

  $findPinCode->save();

  try {

      $this->validatePostLoginRequest($request);

  } catch (HttpResponseException $e) {
      return $this->onBadRequest();
  }

  try {
      if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt(
          $this->getCredentials($request)
      )) {
          return 'asdasd';
          return $this->onUnauthorized();
      }
  } catch (JWTException $e) {
      return $this->onJwtGenerationError();
  }
```

**I receives the following error :**

```
{
  "message": "Undefined index: password",
  "status_code": 500
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codebase you use makes use of `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` package. The `JWTAuth::attempt` method by default makes use of email and password.

The simplest way would be to manually validate the user by the pincode and fetch the user object and generate token using for the user using `JWTAuth::fromUser`

```
$user = User::find($uid);

try {
    if (!$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) {
        return $this->onUnauthorized();
    }
} catch (JWTException $e) {
    return $this->onJwtGenerationError();
}
```